# how to defined variable in state in vuex

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

```
<v-select
          v-model="filterSystem"
          :items="currentSystems"
          :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '400' }"

          class="pa-0 ma-0"
          multiple
          outline
          dense

          persistent-hint
        />


 computed:{
dateRanges() {
  return [
    { text: i18n.t('Latest'), range: [null, null] },
    { text: i18n.t('Hour'), range: [-3600, null] },
    { text: i18n.t('SevenHours'), range: [-3600 * 6, null] },
    { text: i18n.t('TwentyHours'), range: [-3600 * 12, null] },
    { divider: true },
    { text: i18n.t('SelectRange'), range: [0, 0] },
  ]
 },
isDark() {
  return this.$store.getters.getPreference('isDark')
},
 history() {
  return this.item.history.map((h, index) => ({ index: index, ...h }))
},
 currentSystems() {
  return this.$store.getters['alarms/systems']
},
filterSystem: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.alarm.filter.system
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.dispatch('alarms/setFilter', {
      system: value.length > 0 ? value : null
    }).then(() => this.$store.dispatch('alarms/getAlamrs'))
  }
 },
```

}

i have crate systems[] in state and method in getters action and mutation ....but not able to get the data in v-select component.i have updated some of computed property ....i have watched some tutorial ...in the tutorial they use method only or method only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using mapState and accessing the systems value from store like that? 
You can find an example for that on this link: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

Add this to your component:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

computed: {
           ...mapState('alarms', ['systems'])
        },
```

And then your v-select should look like this:

```
        <v-select
          v-model="filterSystem"
          :items="systems"
          :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '400' }"
          class="pa-0 ma-0"
          multiple
          outline
          dense
          persistent-hint
        />
```

Comment: i am working on web app ...that contain lots of data ....and file ....i didn't see any mapState ....one folder that is store have module and module folder have the many store file. web app contain already 2 filter but i want to make one more filter for the app ...so by this i have declared

Comment: const state = { systems:[], filter:{ system: null },const mutations = { SET_SYSTEMS(state, systems): any {
    state.systems = systems
  }},const actions = {getSystems({ commit }) {
    return AlarmsApi.getSystems({}).then(({ systems }) =>
      commit('SET_SYSTEMS', systems)
    )
  }},const getters = {  systems: state => {
    return state.systems.map(r => r.system).sort()
  }}

Comment: actually i'm new in this vuejs and vuex ...so i'm just fallow previous filter which are already defined in store and web app . that why some of place i use s with system ans some of system without s.

Comment: Can you please update your question with code you put in comments? I proposed mapState because that is an easy way to access your store values from the components, doesn't matter if you didn't use it before, it is well explained on the link I posted.

Comment: Not working ...i have applied this above code which you wrote

Comment: hi mario ....any update regarding this ...actually when i used mapState statement in code my web app will not show any thing on local host ...only blank screen is showing.

Comment: If you don't post the error, I can't help you, I updated my answer again, to show you how to import mapState, if you didn't do it.

Comment: now page is loading but v-select component not showing any data "No data available" and not getting any error